# Ruby code for deleting the vowels in a string

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to write code in Ruby that removes all the vowels from a string:

```
def remvowel(string)
  i = 0
  dv_string = []
  while i < string.length
    if (string[i] != "a" || string[i] != "e" || string[i] != "i" || string[i] != "o" || string[i] != "u")
      dv_string.push(i)
      i += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return dv_string.join
end
```

But it's not coming out right. When I run `remvowel("duck")`, it returns `"02"`, as in the index positions of `"dc"`. I'm missing something, but I don't know what.

Comment: Word of general advice - you likely won't see any `while` and `for` loops in ruby code, as there almost always is a better way of doing same thing (most commonly you'll see `each` method used)

Comment: Also, `+= 1` is often (but not always) a code smell in Ruby.

Comment: @sawa Please fill me in - I'm not much of a Ruby user, what's the alternative to += 1?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - What he meant is not that there is an alternative to that particular expression, but rather there is a way of doing it without need of explicitly increment the counter. `while` loop above can be easily substituted with `times` method: `string.length.times do |i|` without need of manual `i` incrementation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could just:

```
string.gsub(/[aeiou]/, '')
```

Or even better:

```
string.tr('aeiou', '')
```

And the best tool for deleting characters in a string is...

```
string.delete('aeiou')
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're pushing `i` instead of `string[i]`.

```
dv_string.push(i)
```

This is what you want:

```
dv_string.push(string[i])
```

However, that's a rather verbose and roundabout way of accomplishing the task. A somewhat more idiomatic Ruby approach would look like any of the ones ndn posted:

```
def remvowel(string)
  string.gsub /[aeiou]/, ''
end
```

or

```
def remvowel(string)
  string.tr 'aeiou',''
end
```

or

```
def remvowel(string)
  string.delete 'aeiou'
end
```

Comment: I think he means it's missing the 3, as in 023 for dck in duck

Comment: Omitting `return` keyword would be even more idiomatic :)

Comment: Didn't know about that. So much simpler! That's one thing I've noticed about the programming tuts I've done. They teach you to do it the long way instead of using pre-defined methods.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it almost right:

```
def remvowel(string)
    i = 0
    dv_string = []

    while i < string.length
        if (string[i] != "a" || string[i] != "e" || string[i] != "i" || string[i] != "o" || string[i] != "u")
            # Push the letter, not i
            dv_string.push(string[i])
            # Don't increment i here
        end

        i += 1
    end

    return dv_string.join
end
```

Your algorithm increments i twice if you encounter a consonant, so you are skipping every second letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way this can be done:

```
s = "Hello, how are you you?"
vowels = "aeiou"
puts (s.chars - vowels.chars).join
#=> Hll, hw r y y?
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your contributions. Thanks to you all (and especially you, Cary Swoveland), I not only know better ways to do this in the future, but even found an answer for my "scenic route" way of doing it!

```
def remvowel(string)
    i = 0
    dv_string = []

    while i < string.length
        dv_string.push(string[i])

        if (string[i] == "a" || string[i] == "e" || string[i] == "i" || string[i] == "o" || string[i] == "u")
            dv_string.delete(string[i])
        end

        i += 1
    end

    return dv_string.join
end
```

Granted, I'm gonna be doing the more sensible way from the responses here from now on, but mission accomplished!

Comment: Please don't post "thank you", especially as an answer. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion board or BBS. Instead it's an online reference book; Would you see "thank you" messages in a text book or encyclopedia? Also, unless your code is going to be your selected answer it's not necessary to show us your final code. Finally, your code isn't a good example of Ruby code or coding style; If you're going to post it please make sure you're following the guidelines as your code would serve as an example to someone who doesn't know how to solve the answer you've asked.

Comment: @MichaelO'Reggio, you should accept an answer so that future readers can more easily find a solution. If the original question was intended to get debug help, edit your code so that it follows [the ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), remove the *"thank you"s* in your answer and mark it as accepted. If your question aimed at finding good ways to remove vowels in a string in Ruby, you can slightly edit your question to point to the fact that the code was just an attempt at solving the problem and mark one of the other answers (like mine wink, wink).